# Mysql sync relational database

Tags: mysql, database, synchronization, relational-database

**My question :**

How can i sync 2 mysql databases (offline local database with master online database) ?

problem is database is relational,and id as always is auto incremenate, so if i just sync using insert it will mess with my referals.

> this for a clinic management app i made, problem is currently its on
>   server but sometimes internet connection goes down/slow on my users
>   clinic, so i need to let him work on offline mode (store every thing
>   to local db) and manually sync (bi-directional) with remote database
>   at end of day.
>   so basically each clinic should have its own local db and let them all sync to central db

example of tables.

db.Cental.users

```
|id|user|clinic  |
|01|demo|day care|
|02|nurs|er      |
|03|demX|day care|
```

db.day care.users

```
|id|user|clinic  |
|01|demo|day care|
|02|demX|day care|
```

(note id doesnt necessarily match between central and local db, yet structure of db on both is identical)

example:
[image: my main database is more complex than this one, but that should do as an example]

database info:

1. each user have many visits,plugins.
2. each visit contain 1user as patient_id, and 1user as doctor_id
3. each plugin have one user, many inputs
4. plugin_inputs have one plugin

i have 2 databases 1 on the server and other hosted locally -for offline mode-

what i want is to be able to sync locally db with online one, but since i have more than 1 user, more than one local db so each one will have nearly same id's while online db should contain all of them combined.

so how can i sync them together ?

i user php/mysql(online)/sqlite(local)

Comment: This is not a PHP question, it is a MySQL question. It is a bad idea to keep 2 tables/databases and then merge them later on, and a lot more hassle. Perhaps you should use the single database and then change your application settings to use that one database server.

Comment: @Husman php : incase i need to use some code to sync them.. reason why i MUST user 2 databases is that local database works on offline mode and user sync it when ever internet is back. as a backup and so he can access it from anywhere.

Comment: You need to iterate over all of the records on the local machine, then for each one (I would recommend exporting this as a CSV or XML/json file), you need to check that it does not exist on the online database, and then insert it as a new record. This is best done when the online database is not being used much (i.e. late at night). The reason for exporting it as a xml/json/csv file is to allow for batch processing, and coding becomes simpler with a structured data format. Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks but not much of a help since that dont solve the relation problem. as the main problem is to insert with correct relation. i can this with php but its gona be annoying code and i got feeling there must be someone out there who already done it so no need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: It is annoying code in PHP, and your database tables and relationships are pretty unique, so your solution will be unique in PHP code. Can you show your table structures fully? - so that we can see what relationships/indexes/PK's/FK's you have.

Comment: When you say "sync", do you mean uni-directional - i.e. "local" to "central", or bi-directional? Does the same data exist everywhere - could a single User be in 2 local databases?

Comment: @NevilleK uni-directional from local->central , and no local user have only 1 database. nice question between!:)

Comment: edited question according to  comment suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things you can do.

Firstly, you could consider a composite primary key for the user table - for instance, you could include "Clinic" in the primary key. That way, you know that even if the auto increment values overlap, you can always uniquely identify the user.

The "visit" table then needs to include patient_clinic and doctor_clinic in the foreign keys.

Alternatively - and far dirtier - you can simply set the auto increment fields for each clinic to start at different numbers: `ALTER TABLE user AUTO_INCREMENT = 10000;` will set the first auto_increment for the user table to 10000; if the next clinic sets it at 20000 (or whatever), you can avoid overlaps (until you exceed that magic number, which is why it's dirty).

Answer (score 1):

I'd be tempted to redesign the application architecture to have an API at the "remote" end and a job that runs at the end of each day at the "local" end to post all the "local" data to the "remote" API.

This way you could have the "local" job create a JSON message similar to this:

```
{ user_visit: 
    { 
      user_id: 1, 
      doctor_id: 1, 
      plugins: [
          {
          plugin_name: name,  
          data: {
              data_field1: "VALUE",
              data_field2: "VALUE2",
              data_fieldxx: "VALUExx"
          }

      ]
    }
}
```

And send each message to the API.  In the API, you would then iterate over the JSON message, reconstructing the relationships and inserting them into the "remote" database accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Create the "id" and "id_offline" column in the local database. make all relationships between tables with "id_offline" and use automatic increment.
The "id" will match the MySQL "id" and will start with a null value.
When sending the data to the server, a check will be made if the "id" is equal to null, if it is, "insert" if not "update", after that use the MySQL "RETURNING" function to return the automatically generated id and return this information to the device that made the request.
When the device receives the new ids, update the "id" column of the local database to be the same as MySQL.